# OpenRAVE issue: E: Unable to find a source package for openrave

Tags: python, ros, robotics, openrave

I try to use IKFast in my Baxter-Robot project. The last command from the baxter tutorial failed:

```
python /path_to_openrave/openrave/python/ikfast.py --robot=baxter_arm.right.rounded.dae --iktype=transform6d --baselink=1 --eelink=10 --freeindex=5 --savefile=baxter_right_arm_ikfast_solver.cpp
```

> ERROR MESSAGE: /openrave/python/ikfast.py", line 9467, in 
>       import openravepy ImportError: No module named openravepy

Because of that I follow the tutorial on openrave.org (http://openrave.org/docs/latest_stable/coreapihtml/installation_linux.html) for setting up OpenRave from the scratch. When I used the last command

```
sudo apt-get build-dep openrave
```

I got this message

> E: Unable to find a source package for openrave

no idea why this happened...

My Qt version is 4.8.6, and gcc is 4.8.4, so that's no problem.

Thanks

Devel

Comment: `openrave` is a Python package and should be installed with `pip install`.

Comment: Sry, it isn't a python package ?